# Sum of Independent exponential random variables 1.0

Tags: integration, summation, random-variables, exponential-function, independence

Help with Exponential Distribution Exercise: Struggling to Eliminate -1

$Let ( X_i \sim \text{Exp}(\theta_1)  and\  ( X_j \sim \text{Exp}(\theta_2) ), determinate ( X_i + X_j = U ).$

$\int_0^u \theta_1 e^{-\theta_1*k}  \cdot \theta_2e^{-\theta_2u+\theta_2k} dk $

$\theta_1\theta_2e^{-\theta_{2}u}\int_0^u e^{\theta_2k-\theta_1k}dk $

after of evaluate

$\theta_1\theta_2e^{-\theta_{2}u} \cdot \dfrac{1}{\theta_1\theta_2}(e^{(\theta_1-\theta_2)u}-{e^0})
 $

$\theta_1\theta_2e^{-\theta_{2}u} \cdot \dfrac{1}{\theta_1\theta_2}(e^{(\theta_1-\theta_2)u}-{1})
 $

The principal problem is that answer is:

$\theta_1\theta_2e^{-\theta_{2}u} \cdot \dfrac{e^{(\theta_1-\theta_2)u}}{\theta_1\theta_2}
 $

I need help, please

Answer (score 0):

If $\theta _2>\theta_1$ (say) then for $s$ small enough $$E(e^{s U})=\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_1-s}\frac{\theta_2}{\theta_2-s}=\frac{1}{\theta_2-\theta_1}\left(\theta_2\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_1-s}-\theta_1\frac{\theta_2}{\theta_2-s}\right)$$$$=\frac{\theta_1\theta_2}{\theta_2-\theta_1}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{su}\left(e^{-\theta_1 u}-e^{-\theta_1 u}\right)du$$ The density of $U$ is $$\frac{\theta_1\theta_2}{\theta_2-\theta_1}\times \left(e^{-\theta_1 u}-e^{-\theta_2 u}\right)$$